# Jasmine Testing toEqual is correct value, still failing test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing a series of tests to demonstrate the value of 'this' in different contexts.

Here is my current Test suite:

```
describe("this keyword", function(){
    it('returns the global context of this', function(){
        expect(globalThis()).toEqual(window);
    });
    it('returns the method context of this', function(){
        expect(methodThis.showThis()).toEqual({ showThis : Function });
    });

});
```

My second test won't pass with this code even though it is the exact value:

```
var methodThis = {
    showThis: function(){
        return this;
    }
};
```

All this function is doing is returning the context of this inside of an object.

Why is this test failing even though the correct toEqual value is being passed to toEqual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jasmine.any](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E) for comparing the function type:

```
describe("this keyword", function(){
    it('returns the method context of this', function(){
        expect(methodThis.showThis()).toEqual({ showThis : jasmine.any(Function) });
    });

});
```